# Modeling a tree of Configurations with Object Oriented Design

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, modeling, object-oriented-analysis

*What is the best OOP way to model the following?:*

There is a set of objects that inherit from class Configurable, and a tree of Configurations/sub-configurations.

- Conceptually, each Configuration object represents the state of all the Configurables, and configurations inherit (and can override) settings from their parents.
- At any given time, one of the Configurations is “active” (you’re using that configuration when you read/write to a Configurable; if a Configuration doesn’t contain a value for a needed parameter, its parent is queried, recursively).
- You can quickly change the "active" configuration at run-time. (Configurables, in my application, will be objects which process real-time MIDI data. MIDI is a relatively slow, real-time stream protocol.)

*Possibilities:*

A: **Store the state of the Configurables in each Configuration**. Each Configuration has a map with the key: (propertyName, ownerObject) which stores the value of that property. Every time a property of a Configurable is accessed or changed, the getter/setter for the Configurable queries the active Configuration (including parent Configurations with getters, if necessary) to retrieve/set its state.

B: **Store the state of each Configurable completely within that object**, as a map with the key: (propertyName, configuration). Every time a property of a Configurable is accessed/changed using regular getter/setter member functions, the Configurable queries this internal map to retrieve/set its state (using the active Configuration). If needed, information about each Configuration can be generated by querying each Configurable.

C: **Some other way?**

Things to consider: saving/restoring Configurations, deleting Configurables and Configurations.

Comment: Do you have some own thoughts on that? Would you like to share them with us please?

Comment: Option B seems like the most OOP-like solution, since the state of the Configurables is encapsulated within the object itself. It's the one I'm leaning towards. But it also means that every time you want to know a bunch of stuff about a Configuration (eg. get a list of settings stored in a Config) you have to dynamically generate that info by searching through all the Configurables.

Comment: Configuration management is generally not something you would implement from scratch, i.e. don't reinvent the wheel. Popular frameworks like Spring handle this for you. Consider investigating some open-source frameworks if you're curious how others have done it.

Comment: @jaco0646 Thanks! I just amended my original question to include an important requirement I’d forgotten: being able to quickly change which config is “active” at any point during run-time.

Comment: @jaco0646 I googled Spring, and found info on how to specify the instantiation of Beans using using xml config files, with and how to create a tree within the xml file of inherited sets of values with which to instantiate the Bean (eg. https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-configuration-inheritance/#:~:text=In%20Spring%2C%20the%20inheritance%20is,to%20override%20the%20inherited%20value.). But...

Comment: @jaco0646 Is it possible, using Spring (or any alternative), to change which config is “active” without having to reinstantiate the Bean (since Spring appears to have one tree of inherited values per Bean, I assume that this single bean would have to contain the entire set of Configurables)? Is it possible to modify the properties of a Bean at run-time and have the new property values saved as an updated xml config file?

Comment: @Mark Seemann Yes, it’s “inheritance” and (possibly) “sub-typing”, as you explained. I don’t know how to turn that explanation into an OOP design, though. How would that be done?

Comment: @user10264746 https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/12/composite-as-a-monoid